# Expecting member declaration when adding code to Flutter MainActivity

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin

I'm getting the error "Expecting member declaration" on `startLockTask()` function call when adding this code to MainActivity.kt file in a Flutter project.  How can I resolve this issue?

```
package com.iluvwireless.secure_phone

import android.view.View
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
    startLockTask()
}
```

Comment: Because this is incorrect kotlin code. What are you trying to do? When you want to start the Lock task? When the Activity is started?

Comment: All the code you see was generated by Android Studio when I started a new Flutter project.  The only thing I added was the `startLockTask()` call.  So as it stands the Kotlin code is correct.  I just need to know why I'm getting that error.  That same function works as is in an Android only project.

Comment: The code of the class is correct. But you cannot call a method there. This code will also not work in a Android only project. Since the Kotlin compiler will not compile that. See: https://pl.kotl.in/iAtUWF-AK So please specify what you want to do, then I can help you. Do you want to start the lock task when starting the activity?

Comment: Yes exactly, start the lock task when starting the Activity.  And yes I know this is an Android only solution, I generally use Flutter for everything now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already commented: The issue here is, that this is no valid kotlin code. There, where you call the `stackLockTask()` Method is no place where the kotlin compiler expects you to call a method. What you can do there is defining member variables or a method of the activity.

See Kotlin starter [guide here](https://kotlinlang.org/).

So what you want to achieve is: Calling the `startLockTask()` method as soon as the activity starts. The callback method of the activity startup is called `onCreate()`. So overriding this method and placing there your `startLockTask()` call should do the trick.

This would then look like:

```
package com.iluvwireless.secure_phone

import android.view.View
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        stackLockTask()
    } 
}
```